# How do I create a swagger example with Swashbuckle to show an attribute accepts multiple types?

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, swashbuckle

I've added a `Dictionary<string, object>` to a pre-existing request body and I want to create a custom example to show that it accepts multiple types. However, currently it only shows that it accepts strings.

I've tried `<example>...</example>`, `[JsonProperty]` and swashbuckle annotations, but so far have been unsuccessful.

Current Swagger example:

```
{
  ...,
  "properties": {
    "additionalProp1": "string",
    "additionalProp2": "string",
    "additionalProp3": "string"
  }
}
```

Wanted Swagger example:

```
{
  ...,
  "properties": {
    "additionalProp1": "string",
    "additionalProp2": 123,
    "additionalProp3": true
  }
}
```

Request class:

```
public class RequestBody
{
    public RequestBody(Dictionary<string, object>? properties = null)
    {
        Properties = properties;
    }

    /// <summary>...</summary>
    public Dictionary<string, object>? Properties { get; }
}
```